# Xamarin: Resource.Designer.cs doesn't update when I make changes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I got a problem with my Resource.Designer.cs. I spent well over an hour on google trying to find a solution, but I can't find a fix for my problem.
When I add a button or a text field in the Main.axml editor thing, it doesn't update the Resource.Designer.cs file. So when I write "var label = FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);" it shows a red line under the "textView1" because there is nothing about it in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

Even worse:
When I open a blank file and name it as "App1" (the default it was) and add all the things to get the same as in this tutorial, it can't detect the Resource.Layout.Main, since it generates the names wrong.
Screenshot of MainActivity.cs: http://puu.sh/tqsNr/8ac98a5b08.png
Screenshot of Resource.Designer.cs: http://puu.sh/tqsOv/dd1de7328f.png
This is because the namespace in MainActivity is "App1", and it generates the namespace name in Resource.Designer as "application".

How can I fix this? I have very limited time because I have to use this for a school project.

Comment: There are many possibly workarounds for issues like these. What have you tried yourself? As the question is stated right now, you are likely to receive many different answers, as the question is too broad.

Comment: Could you please check the `RootNameSpace` tag value of  `YourProjectName.csproj` file?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Not soon after I posted my question, and before your reply I found out that the default names of the namespace were different. This was indeed the problem for my second problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting this file, reopening Xamarin Studio/VS and rebuilding Android project over? 
Do you have any compilation problems when you build your Android project?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and I figured it was a Xamarin bug.  But in this case, it was because I had left a --> in my strings.xml file after I had removed some comments.  I saw the compile warning deep in the error list.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, try adding a new `.axml` file to project. Worked for me (you can delete the file after it works).